# PostgreSQL EF.Core DB-First Invalid DB Model: No mapping to a relational type can be found for property 'Db.Order.High' with the CLR type 'bool'

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I'm using Asp.net core 3 C# with Entity Framework core 3 and I'm trying to use a PostgreSQL server.

This is my Model containing the bool **High** which is named in the Exception:

```
public class Order : IEquatable<Order>, ICloneable
    {
            public long Id { get; set; }
            public long? DeviceId { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            public Device Device { get; set; }

            public long? OriginOrderId { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Date)]
            public DateTime RoutineStart { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [EnumDataType(typeof(Routine))]
            public Routine Routine { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            public int Pin { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public bool High { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            public int TimeInMilliseconds { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }

            [NotMapped]
            public bool Ready { get; set; }

            public OrderState State { get; set; } = OrderState.Idle;
}
```

The Context is a Scoped Service which should not matter, but...

```
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
              options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("postgre")), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

I tried to add a initial Migration with **Add-Migration init** and this is the whole Exception:

```
add-migration init Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]  Entity Framework Core 3.0.0 initialized 'ApplicationDbContext' using provider 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL' with options: None
System.InvalidOperationException: No mapping to a relational type can be found for property 'Webservice.Models.Db.Order.High' with the CLR type 'bool'.  
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMappingSourceExtensions.GetMapping(IRelationalTypeMappingSource typeMappingSource, IProperty property) 
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Diff(IProperty source, IProperty target, DiffContext diffContext)+MoveNext() 
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.DiffCollection[T](IEnumerable`1 sources, IEnumerable`1 targets, DiffContext diffContext, Func`4 diff, Func`3 add, Func`3 remove, Func`4[] predicates)+MoveNext() 
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext() 
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Diff(TableMapping source, TableMapping target, DiffContext diffContext)+MoveNext() 
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.DiffCollection[T](IEnumerable`1 sources, IEnumerable`1 targets, DiffContext diffContext, Func`4 diff, Func`3 add, Func`3 remove, Func`4[] predicates)+MoveNext() 
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext() 
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Sort(IEnumerable`1 operations, DiffContext diffContext) 
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetDifferences(IModel source, IModel target) 
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(String migrationName, String rootNamespace, String subNamespace, String language) 
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType) 
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType) 
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0(
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0(
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action) No mapping to a relational type can be found for property 'Webservice.Models.Db.Order.High' with the CLR type 'bool'.
```

A workaround for this would be to Inherit "ViewOrder" from Order while only Order is stored in the DB:

Order

```
public int high { get; set; }
```

ViewOrder : Order

```
public bool High
{
    get => high == 1;
    set => high = value ? 1 : 0;
}
```

But i would rather not do this. There must be something like **bit** in T-SQL.
I would really aprecciate if someone could explain me how to use bool in a PostgreSQL Model.

Comment: Check you have added the dependency to npgsql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to delete all old migrations. It showed this error about "bool" but the error had nothing to do with the errormessage. 
I dont get it, but deleting all migrations and initializing the database new solved it.

Answer (score 6):

PostgreSQL actually hosts a _EFMigrations Table. The error starts propagating from there. I remember facing one such issue when i was trying to migrate from SQLServer to PostgreSQL with .NET Core and EFCore. 
If you were trying to do that

use this command which will let you rollback all migrations one by one.

```
EntityframeworkCore\Update-Database 0
```

Make a new Migration by running

```
EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration Init
```

PostGreSQL should now be able to keep track of all the migrations and the Database State.

Comment: i deleted all migrations and it worked, but thanks! i will definetly use your solution next time

Answer (score 3):

As @Michael Santos Suggested
**Problem:** 
For me Actually First i had created the project using the default authentication from visual studio which create a migration for sql server database whereas i require to connect my web app to the Postgresql. So when i run Update-Database i shows me the error of "null reference" and when i add new migration it shows me error of "no mapping" because of the default migration already added
**Solution:**
Delete the Old Migration and ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot
Create new Migration  (Add-Migration migrationName )
Update Database

Answer (score 2):

https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/basic.html

to see this, 
PostgreSQL type need use [boolean] to Default .NET type [bool]

Comment: i tried the `[Column(TypeName = "boolean")]` attribute, but this did not change the exception